# GCP storage Bucket transfer

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-data-transfer

I am looking to transfer data from one bucket to another bucket in 2 different google cloud account. Is it possible to transfer data from one GCP Account to another GCP Account? If yes, what are the steps for that ?

Also let me know, What are the charges will applied to both GCP accounts ?

Answer (score 1):

There is a service: [`Storage Transfer Service`](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs).

> Storage Transfer Service allows you to quickly import online data into Cloud Storage. You can also set up a repeating schedule for transferring data, as well as transfer data within Cloud Storage, from one bucket to another.

This feature is the one you might be interested in: [`Transfer between Cloud Storage buckets`](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs/create-manage-transfer-program#transfer_between_buckets).

You can also do it through the Console: go to Navigation Menu / Storage / Transfer.
Click on `Yes, conitnue to data transfer`.

[image]

Click on `Create Transfer job`. There you can type the bucket name in the Source field: `gs://BUCKETNAMTE`. This action should be performed in the destination project.

[image]

About the `pricing`, here is the [`Documentation`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing). The main billed charges should for:

- [Operations](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-pricing).

> Operation charges apply when you perform operations within Cloud Storage. An operation is an action that makes changes to or retrieves information about buckets and objects in Cloud Storage.

I think the most operations you would perform should be [class A](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#operations-by-class) for writing on the destination Bucket Project and class B in the origin Bucket Project. The pricing depends on which storage class is each Bucket. Anyway, I think you can calculate it with the table of the docs.

- [Network](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#network-buckets).

> Network egress within Google Cloud applies when you move or copy data from one Cloud Storage bucket to another or when another Google Cloud service accesses data in your Cloud Storage bucket.

You can check the locations of your buckets and estimate the pricing.

- [Data Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing#storage-pricing).

> Data storage costs apply to the at-rest storing of your data in Cloud Storage. Select the desired location from the drop-down list to see the data storage rates that apply in that location.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the volume of data you want to transfer, you can use either `gsutil` or the [Storage Transfer Service](https://cloud.google.com/storage-transfer/docs). I'd use the latter if are moving more than, say, 1 TB of data.

If the source and destination are in the same location and storage class it will be a fast (metadata-only) operation; otherwise it will require byte copying. Either way, note that you are copying, not "transferring" the data (so, you'll need to delete the original data after the copies complete, if that's what you want done).

Pricing is covered at https://cloud.google.com/storage/pricing.

Answer (score 0):

The catch is that you need to give the service account the access for write on the other project (destination project).

Once that is provided you can transfer the data from source bucket to destination.